# "I'm not afraid" vs "I don't afraid"

Tags: negation, do-support

Sometimes I hear people say 'I don't afraid...'
For example: 'I don't afraid to be alone'
Or 'I don't afraid of the darkness'.

But is it right?
I've always thought that we can only say: 'I'm not afraid of something' of 'I'm not afraid to do something'
And with 'don't' we can say only to someone: 'Don't be afraid'.

Is it possible to say 'I don't afraid', 'You don't afraid' etc.?

Comment: You may want to clarify your question: It's *possible* to say it -- you already state you've heard people say it, so it must be possible -- it's quite possible to say wrong things; this is one. I suspect you don't mean to ask whether it's possible, but whether it's grammatical English.

Comment: Where do you hear people say that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is it possible to say 'I don't afraid', 'You don't afraid' etc.?

No. It **is not** possible. See, the verb "**be**" (**is, are, was**..) is a *[copular verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)).* When the copular **is** or an auxiliary verb is present in a clause, we do not use the so-called **[do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support#With_the_negation_not)** when forming a negative version of that clause. We add **not** instead.

> It **is** possible. ("is" is a copular verb)
>   It **is not** possible.
>
> It **was** possible.
>   It **was not** possible.
>
> He **will** laugh. ("will" is an [auxiliary verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb))
>   He **will not** laugh.

Comment: It's perfectly possible [to say or use it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22don%27t+afraid%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22I+don%27t+afraid%22), however ungrammatical it may be; the construct "I don't afraid' caught on as a meme, as @Chris Petheram  [has pointed out](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/76763/27803). So learners will enocunter this construction, but should know that it is **slang**.

Comment: Indeed, even among native speakers there are plenty of local dialects around the world that are rife with ungrammatical constructs : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnlhKWeDWMA

Comment: I've never heard anyone say "I don't afraid".  The only slang I've heard to replace "I'm not afraid" is "I aint never scarred".

Comment: CopperKettle is a pretty cool guy, eh tells people it's impossible to say certain words and he doesn't afraid of anything.

Answer (score 32):

As other answers have pointed out, this is not good grammar, and you are correct that it should be 'be afraid' rather than 'do afraid'.

The reason you still hear it is likely due to a troll post on 4chan which became a meme and, as such, was perpetuated by native speakers, even though they knew it was wrong.

The original post was in December 2007 and concerned Halo / Master Chief.

Potentially NSFW KnowYourMeme reference:
http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pretty-cool-guy

Comment: It is very good to know the origins of a slang. Nice research job Chris.

Comment: Chris is a pretty cool guy, posts answers and doesn't afraid of anything

Comment: @mikeTheLiar  _StackExchange_ is a pretty cool guy...

Answer (score 16):

You can say

- "I don't fear `<x>`."
- "I don't have any fear."
- "I don't **feel** afraid."
- "I'm not afraid."

*Afraid* is something you can be (adjective), not something you can do (verb).

Unfortunately, "I don't afraid" sounds very wrong to native speakers.  Unlike some subtle mistakes that we easily overlook, this one is quite distracting and obvious, at least written down.

The meaning is still clear, once you stop and figure it out.

Answer (score 14):

All dictionaries list **afraid** as an adjective so you can't use it as if it were a verb.

Furthermore, the adjective in question can be used only after linking verbs (for example **be** or **feel**):

> I feel afraid.
>
> Don't be afraid.

[Be careful!](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/afraid)

> Afraid is used only after linking verbs such as be and feel. Don't use it in front of a noun. For example, don't talk about 'an afraid child'. However, you can talk about 'a frightened child'.
> He was acting like a frightened kid.

The link I provided explains further the use of the word **afraid**.

Answer (score 5):

Afraid is used like this: to be afraid of something.

Perhaps the original source was mixing afraid and fear. Fear can be used together with 'do'.

For example: 'I don't fear ghosts' means the same as 'I am not afraid of ghosts'.